# How do I do multiple file operations in flex

Tags: flex-lexer

flex 2.6.4

bison 3.8.2

Win 7/10/11-x64

I am trying to parse an 'include' file and need to stack multiple buffers. The Flex manual describes the Flex support for this in Chapter 11, Multiple Input Buffers, but doesn't seem to store/restore filenames, YYLTYPE data structures or any internal variables. Do I have to build my own stack to handle this?

Comment: Yes you do need to provide it yourself.